# What was the relationship between the Imperial Rule Assistance Association and the Imperial General Headquarters?

Tags: world-war-two, imperial-japan

I am trying to write an analysis of the bureaucracy in Japan that led to their decision to enter the War in 1941. I see both the [Imperial Rule Assistance Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Rule_Assistance_Association)(IRAA) and [Imperial General Headquarters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_General_Headquarters) (IGH) as players, but can't seem to understand what their relationship is. They seem to be very similar bodies.

It seems to me, based on some research with the Oxford Companion to WWII that both served as "sounding boards" to the defense establishment.

Comment: What has your [preliminary research shown](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote/785#785)?  Superficially, (not my field), one is the creation of the prime minister and the other is a military organization.  "The Imperial General Staff Headquarters was completely independent of the civilian government of the Empire of Japan, including the Cabinet and even the Prime Minister of Japan. " [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_General_Headquarters)

Comment: Added to the body of the post.

Comment: You might want to look at the available postwar Japanese Monographs - http://ibiblio.org/hyperwar/Japan/Monos/

Comment: @Bochur613 IRAA was primarily "civilian" government i.e. organization that "unified" Japanese non-military life, while IGH simply coordinated between IJA and IJN. This is simplistic description, but overall IRAA represented interests of bureaucracy and industrialists, IGH of the military.

Comment: Look deeper into both. You almost certainly discover one was supported by the navy, and the other by the army.